# Как отмасштабировать canvas по размеру image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть сетка `grid` и в ней картинка, которая автоматически масштабируется (`Stretch="Uniform"`). В этой же ячейке находится `Canvas`  с элементами. Как сделать так, чтобы `Canvas` имел те же итоговые размеры и то же положение, что и `image` (чтобы по сути накладывались друг на друга).

Answer (score 1):

допустим, `Image` называется `photoTabImage`

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=HorizontalAlignment}" 
        Height="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Height}"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Width}"
        Margin="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Margin}"
        VerticalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=VerticalAlignment}"
        />
```

[Мой же ответ отсюда по похожей проблеме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423665/wpf-dragenter-not-firing-on-image/29426970#29426970)

Comment: +1, но я бы посоветовал `ActualWidth`, т. к. `Width` может быть не задано (и я не уверен, сработает ли в этом случае).